# Click each button with the same ID

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have two buttons with the same ID:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="//do something" id="theID">button 1</button>

<button type="submit" onclick="//do something" id="theID">button 2</button>
```

I would like to click both the buttons using prototype.  So far I've tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
$('theID').each(function(item) { 
   item.click();
});
```

How can I easily click both buttons using prototype?

Comment: Two elements with the same ID is invalid HTML/XML (whichever you're using). As such behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have two buttons with the same ID

There's the problem. Use classes instead of IDs; by design and definition IDs *must* be unique. Stuff just plain won't work if they aren't.

```
$('.clickable').each(function(item) { 
   item.click();
});
```

And

```
<button type="submit" class="clickable">button 1</button>

<button type="submit" class="clickable">button 2</button>
```

Comment: Prototype's CSS selector function is `$$`, `$` is only for `id || element`

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the same id is a bad idea in general. It is incorrect syntax, as an elements id must begin with a letter and can only be given to one element.

You cannot have two elements with the same id.